# Why does cursor position on >> and << go to start of line?

Tags: vimrc

Whenever I press `<<` or `>>` in insert or normal mode, I lose the cursor position, as it always goes back to the start of the line. Is there a setting to fix this?

Here is where I am right now, but am having some trouble figuring out why the below isn't working in normal mode:

```
inoremap            <leader>]   <C-O>>>
inoremap            <leader>[   <C-O><<
nnoremap    <exp>   <leader>]   col('.') == 1 ? '>>' : "D>>A<C-O>P<Esc>`["
nnoremap    <exp>   <leader>[   col('.') == 1 ? '<<' : "D<<A<C-O>P<Esc>`["
vnoremap            <leader>]   >gv
vnoremap            <leader>[   <gv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is called `set nostartofline`. However, it's a global which affects many(!) other commands in Vim and I'd rather *not* suggest to use it.

Comment: I think `set nostartofline` makes a lot of sense in most cases.

Comment: @Biggybi I'm not so sure. For example, many people (and even many scripts) expect `gg` to go to the first char in file, not to the first line.

Comment: Indeed, I never though of that.

Comment: @Matt does my solution below seem adequate then to deal with this issue, or is there a better way to basically ignore `nostartofline` for the `<<`, `>>` commands?

Comment: @David542 Personally I just don't do anything with it. Okay, sometimes you got to the start of the line forcefully. And so what?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is overkill, but this is what I end up doing to 'keep the cursor position' when in insert and normal mode:

```
inoremap    <expr>  <leader>]   col('.') == 1 ? '<C-O>>>' : '<C-O>D<C-O>>><C-O>A<C-O>P<Esc>`[i'
inoremap    <expr>  <leader>[   col('.') == 1 ? '<C-O><<' : '<C-O>D<C-O><<<C-O>A<C-O>P<Esc>`[i'
nnoremap    <expr>  <leader>]   col('.') == 1 ? '>>' : 'D>>A<C-O>P<Esc>`['
nnoremap    <expr>  <leader>[   col('.') == 1 ? '<<' : 'D<<A<C-O>P<Esc>`['
vnoremap            <leader>]   >gv
vnoremap            <leader>[   <gv
```

Any suggestions on how this could be improved would be great.

---

**Update**: there's already a way to do this in `insert` mode so we can use that to our advantage. The mapping then becomes:

```
inoremap <leader>]   <C-T>
inoremap <leader>[   <C-D>
nnoremap <leader>]   i<C-T><Esc>`[
nnoremap <leader>[   i<C-D><Esc>`[
vnoremap <leader>]   >gv
vnoremap <leader>[   <gv
```